# I'm sure this is not supposed to work but it does

Tags: c, memory, dynamic, free, realloc

This is a function used to reallocate some memory on a dynamic array. I have typedef'd `struct lottery` to `lot`. I am passing by reference the array of structures (`a`) and the new size I want it to have (`n`). I am declaring a temporary array (`b`) so I can realloc to `a`.

My question is: I am creating some bytes on the heap with `b = realloc()` etc., but if I `free(b)` before I quit the function it doesn't work properly. If I call it again `b == NULL` becomes `true`, but if I remove the `free(b)` it works just fine, but I think that is not right thing because I am leaving garbage bytes on the heap. Can someone please explain to me the problem?

```
lot *Enterd(lot **a, int n) {
    lot *b = NULL;
    b = (lot *)realloc(*a, n * sizeof(lot));
    if (b == NULL) {
        printf("Memory could not be allocated for the new input.\n");
        return NULL;
   }
   *a = b;
   free(b);
   return *a;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`b = realloc(*a, X)` frees the memory associated with `*a` and allocates a new allocation of size `X`, stored in `b`.

Now when you do `*a = b`, both `*a` and `b` reference this new allocation.

After `free(b)`, that allocation is released and both `b` and `*a` become invalid pointers. At that point `return *a` has undefined behavior.

If you don't free `b`, all is fine. You don't leak memory because you still have a pointer to it: Both via `*a` (which references a variable in the caller) and the function's return value.

(Also, don't cast `realloc()`.)

Comment: Thank you Tom Zych and melpomene.Why shouldn't i cast it?In uni we learnt that realloc returns a void* and we should cast it. (?)

Comment: @Edward No, `malloc` and `realloc` return a `void *` so you *don't* have to cast it. A `void *` pointer can be implicitly converted to any object pointer type. On the other hand, casting can hide problems: http://c-faq.com/malloc/mallocnocast.html

Comment: I will ask my proffesor,but thanks for the feedback and the help anyway!